# when duplicates found keep row if cell is a certain value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that returns this result.  How do I write the query to     say, the if email is the same, only return the row where IsActive = 1?

```
SubID = Unique

| SubID | EMail | IsActive |
| -------------- | -------------- | -------------- |
| 123 | hello@acme.com            | 1 |
| 456 | hello@acme.com            | 0 |
| 789 | hi@acme.com               | 1 |
| 165 | bye@acme.com              | 0 |

Running the query would result in

| SubID | EMail | IsActive |
| -------------- | -------------- | -------------- |
| 123 | hello@acme.com            | 1 |
| 789 | hi@acme.com               | 1 |
| 165 | bye@acme.com              | 0 |

Another example

| SubID | EMail | IsActive |
| -------------- | -------------- | -------------- |
| 123 | hello@acme.com            | 0 |
| 456 | hello@acme.com            | 0 |
| 789 | hi@acme.com               | 1 |
| 165 | bye@acme.com              | 0 |

Running the query would result in

| SubID | EMail | IsActive |
| -------------- | -------------- | -------------- |
| 123 | hello@acme.com            | 0 |
| 789 | hi@acme.com               | 1 |
| 165 | bye@acme.com              | 0 |

Thanks!
```

Sorry for the poor formatting but SO keeps saying "Your post appears to contain code..."

Comment: Is `SubID` unique? Is there only one IsActive=1 for each email? Edit your question to clarify.

Comment: SubID is unique.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Rank your rows with `ROW_NUMBER`. Only keep the best-ranked row per email.

```
select subid, email, isactive
from
(
  select
    subid, email, isactive,
    row_number() over (partition by email order by isactive desc, subid) as rn
  from mytable
) ranked
where rn = 1;
```

Comment: I think the issue w/ this suggestion is that the table could have hundreds of email addresses, some of them unique, and some of them not.  Not sure if that makes sense.

Comment: oh wait, i see what you mean by partition thanks!